# Get URL of the request sender with HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, servlets, dns

How do you get the source domain using HttpServletRequest?
Source domain is the requester's domain.

Thanks.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You could do either

```
// gets client (browser)'s hostname
String host = request.getRemoteHost();
```

OR

```
// get the server's domain name.
String domain = new URL(request.getRequestURL().toString()).getHost();
```

Comment: `getRemoteHost()` returns client's (or proxy's) host.

Comment: @BalusC: Yes, I realised now. Updated the answer. :)

Comment: The client hostname only works if Java receives the request from the browser directly. If Java is behind something like an F5 BIG-IP, you should use request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR") or whatever request header is passed in with the client hostname to get the actual client hostname. request.getRemoteHost() will just give you the IP or domain name of the load balancer since that is what sends the requests to Java.

Answer (score 2):

To get the source domain you can use `request.getHeader("origin")`
especially if the requests have to pass through a proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

Hostname request

```
InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
String hostname = ip.getHostName();
out.print("Your current IP address : " + ip+"\n");
out.print("Your current Hostname : " + hostname);
```